# Spring Data Neo4j get an entity and set it as relationship to another entity

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

I have a little Spring Data Neo4j(SDN) project. I have 2 entities: Product and Category.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "BELONGS_TO", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Category category;
}
```

and

```
@NodeEntity
public class Category {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "CHILD", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I create a new Product I want to get a Category by name from the database as assign it to the Product. The code is:

```
public Product save(Product product) {
    Category dbCategory = categoryRepository.findByName(product.getCategory().getName());
    product.setCategory(dbCategory);

    return productRepository.save(product);
}
```

What SDN does is the following: it removes the CHILD relationship of the category  which was found in the seach and it's parent and creates one between the Product and the Category.

What can I do to keep both relationships?

Comment: What version of Neo4j OGM and Spring Data Neo4J are you using?

Comment: I am using only one maven depenency which is spring-data-neo4j version 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Does the dbCategory category instance have children collection with expected relationships?

Comment: categoryRepository.findByName method uses the following query:"MATCH (category:Category) WHERE category.name = {0} RETURN category". So only the category without any relationships are retrieved.